# How do I have Twilio make a silent call that only sends digits, not voice via mp3/wav?

Tags: python, twilio, twilio-twiml

I'm writing a small program to check my voicemail and email the recording to me at set intervals. Here's the python code for the call portion, at least up to testing basic call & AUDIX option tree navigation once the call connects:

```
from twilio.rest import TwilioRestClient

# put your own credentials here
ACCOUNT_SID = ""
AUTH_TOKEN = ""

client = TwilioRestClient(ACCOUNT_SID, AUTH_TOKEN)
ext = ""
ext_passwd = ""
digs = "wwwwww#ww" + ext + "wwww" + ext_passwd + "#wwwwww2"


call = client.calls.create(
        to="+",
        from_="+",
        url="",
        send_digits=digs,
        record="true"
)

print call.sid
```

The `url` parameter is required, and it seems the target has to be TwiML containing a reference to an audio file that will play when the call connects. I want a silent call, at least from that end, and just to send the digits necessary to navigate my voice mail.

I assume I'm missing something? Or do I really need to host a TwiML file, and reference an "empty" mp3 with a second or two of silence in it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing the send_digits and record parameters, instead use a url which describes a similar flow in  TwiML.

In the XML returned at url, you can use the digits attribute of the [`<Play>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/play#attributes-digits) tag to send dialpad digits and the [`<Record>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/record) tag to capture the subsequent audio on call.  You could even [transcribe](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/record#attributes-transcribe)  the voicemails to text this way.

Here's an example of what the TwiML at url might look like:

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
    <Play digits="wwwwww#ww1234wwww4321#wwwwww2"></Play>
    <Record timeout="10" transcribe="true" transcribeCallback="/handle_transcribe" />
</Response>`

Comment: This is now working. Oddly though, the recording will not start until all of the "digits" have completed, even with trim set to "do-not-trim". I'll have to play around to see what can be done about that, otherwise I won't be able to iterate through messages. That will be a new question though, if necessary.